# Firebase CLI not deploying any Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I have an Angular project where I am trying to deploy a single firebase function.

This is what my functions directory looks like:

[image: My functions directory]

When I deploy these function with the command `firebase deploy --only functions` the output looks normal and no errors:

```
PS C:\Users\project-directory> firebase deploy --only functions

=== Deploying to 'firebase-project-name'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run build

> build
> tsc

+  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: cleaning up build files...

+  Deploy complete!

Project Console: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/project-name/overview
```

`src/user/index.ts` file with the function I am trying to deploy:

```
import functions = require('firebase-functions');
import admin = require('firebase-admin');

// import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
// import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

const FieldValue = require('firebase-admin').firestore.FieldValue;

const db = admin.firestore();

/**
 * Add user to firestore
 */
export const createProfile = async (userRecord: any) => {
    const uid = userRecord.uid;
    const admin = false;
    const email = userRecord.email;
    const photoURL = userRecord.photoUrl || 'enter shortened url for default image';
    const name = userRecord.displayName || 'New User';
    const spouse = userRecord.spouse || 'TBA';
    const forumUserName = userRecord.forumUserName || 'New Username set by admin';
    const address = userRecord.address || 'TBA';
    const suburb = userRecord.suburb || 'TBA';
    const state = userRecord.state || 'QLD';
    const postCode = userRecord.postCode || '2000';
    const homePhone = userRecord.homePhone || '02 1234 5678';
    const mobilePhone = userRecord.mobilePhone || '0400 123 456';
    const memNum = userRecord.memNum || 123;
    const timestamp = FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
    const memType = userRecord.memType || 'Nominated';
    const memStatus = userRecord.memStatus || `Pending`;
    const isStateCoord = userRecord.isStateCoord || false;
    const stateCoordState = userRecord.stateCoordState || 'QLD';
    //const newUserRef = db.doc(`users/${uid}`)

    // Convert any date to timestamp for consistency

    try {
        return await db
            .collection(`users`)
            .doc(userRecord.uid)
            .set({
                uid: uid,
                email: email,
                photoURL: photoURL,
                fullName: name,
                mDOB: timestamp,
                spouse: spouse,
                sDOB: timestamp,
                forumUserName: forumUserName,
                address: address,
                suburb: suburb,
                state: state,
                postCode: postCode,
                homePhone: homePhone,
                mobilePhone: mobilePhone,
                memNum: memNum,
                memType: memType,
                memStatus: memStatus,
                memDueDate: timestamp,
                lastLoginDate: timestamp,
                joined: timestamp,
                updated: timestamp,
                admin: admin,
                isAdmin: admin,
                isStateCoord: isStateCoord,
                stateCoordState: stateCoordState,
            });
    } catch (message) {
        return console.error(message);
    }
};

exports.authOnCreate = functions.auth.user().onCreate(createProfile);
```

`src/index.ts` file imports the above file:

```
import * as user from './user';
export const createProfile = user.createProfile
```

The issue is that I am not seeing the function appear in the Firebase console.

[image: Firebase Console Functions Screen]

What am I overlooking?

Comment: You need to declare ‘ functions.https.onRequest ’. And put ur code inside this method. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started Check chapter 5

Comment: Thanks chichi for the useful link. However, is that not what I have done with this line of code:

`exports.authOnCreate = functions.auth.user().onCreate(createProfile);` in the `src/user/index.ts` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two different export syntaxes in `src/user/index.ts`:

```
export const createProfile = async (userRecord: any) => { /* ... */ }
```

```
exports.authOnCreate = functions.auth.user().onCreate(createProfile);
```

Use one, or the other, not both. They are incompatible with each other.

```
export const createProfile = async (userRecord: any) => { /* ... */ }
export const authOnCreate = functions.auth.user().onCreate(createProfile);
```

Then in your main `src/index.ts`, import the Cloud Function export, not the plain function:

```
import { authOnCreate } from './user'; // import specific parts for the best performance when transpiled
export const createProfile = authOnCreate;
```

Comment: Thank you samthecodingman, I realised the same thing pretty much the same time you answered. Nevertheless, thank you and for pointing out the syntax mistake!

Answer (score 0):

In the original code I posted for you, createProfile was a const not an export.

Out of the box, should work just fine. The only difference I see is you've dropped the code into a user sub directory.

Again no issue and probably ok for readability.

Might be poor practice on my part, but ALL of my functions are in one file. Even when extensions are installed, they go into the same index.js(ts) file. Then if I modify a function I use `firebase deploy --only functions:functionName`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Michael. I think your way is fine. If I had not modularized the code I would not have the above issue. So there is a point to having less files/code to worry about. Having said that, I followed the Google guidelines that recommended grouping the functions into logical domains.